# Invalid block tag: expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'

Tags: django, django-templates

I don't understand the error. It complains for endif while it is there.

```
{% if pdf_enable %}
    {% download_url request.get_full_path "Download as Excel" %}
{% endif %}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Might be helpful to post the full template

Comment: Have you remembered to load the module containing the `download_url` template tag?

Comment: Just came back to answer and surprised to find 2 replies already. Thanks for replying my Stack buddies... :D

@Alasdair: You are right I had forgotten to add what you have mentioned. Came back to say that and found you very accurate answer. :)

How to close this thread now??? :/

Comment: I've added the comment as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to [load the custom template tag set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#load) containing the `download_url` tag.

For example, if the `download_url` tag was in a module called `download_tags`, you would add the following to your template.

```
{% load download_tags %}
```